# Variables not showing up in bat file my program made

Tags: batch-file

Ok so I have my batch file make a file and save some variables in it but nothing is there.

```
set x=5
set y=5

echo set x=%x%> save.bat
echo set y=%y%>>save.bat

set x=1
set y=1
call save.bat

echo %x% %y%

pause>nul
exit
```

So the batch file finds nothing and echo's "1 1" but it allso says "set x=" and "set y=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
echo set "x=%x%"> save.bat
echo set "y=%y%">>save.bat
```

As an alternative you can use

```
>save.bat  echo set x=%x%
>>save.bat echo set y=%y%
```